# Laravel date validation fails with jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquerydatetimepicker

In my **blade file** I have defined:-

```
<div class="createMesh_row date" id="event_date_div">
    <label>Event Date</label>
    {{ Form::text('event_date','',array('id'=>'event_date','readonly', 'class' => '')) }}
    <i class="fa fa-calendar eventdate"></i>
    {{ $errors->first('event_date','<span class="error">:message</span>') }}
</div>
```

In my **js** file:-

```
 $( "#event_date,#target_date" ).datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
     minDate: 0        
  });
```

I have defined **rule** for this:-

```
 $rules=[
            'title'       =>'required',
            'type'        =>'required',
            'privacy'     =>'required',
            'target_date' =>'required|date|date_format:"mm-dd-yyyy"',

  //  tried 'target_date' =>'required|date|date_format:"mm/dd/yyyy"',
  //  tried 'target_date' =>'required|date|date_format:"d/m/Y"',
  //  tried'target_date' =>'required|date_format:d-m-Y', 
  //  not working

            'occasion'    =>'required'
        ];
```

**Errors**:-

```
[target_date] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The target date is not a valid date.
                    [1] => The target date does not match the format mm-dd-yyyy.
                )
```

Comment: Try dumping the input to see how the date looks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Wrote

```
'target_date' =>'required|date_format:"m/d/Y"',
```

and in Js,
 Do not define date format.

```
$("#target_date,#event_date").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        //  dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', // Hide this line
        minDate: 0
});
```

Working fine for me :)

Answer (score 5):

First, you should use either `date` or `date_format` when validating a field, not both.

Second, the correct format for `mm-dd-yyyy` is `m-d-Y`, so the validation should look like this:

```
'target_date' =>'required|date_format:"m-d-Y"',
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check and let you know.

Comment: I got the issue brother. +1 for your answer.

Comment: I have edited some portion of your answer. and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In JS:

```
$( "#event_date,#target_date" ).datepicker({
    // changeMonth: true,
    // changeYear: true,
       viewMode: 'years',
       format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',    
});
```

In Laravel:

```
'target_date' =>'required|date',
```